# Task Scheduler is automatically creating a new Logs folder in the current directory

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task that will execute randomProgram.exe(C#, .NET Framework console application) every 5 minutes. Sometimes a new Logs folder is created in the current directory(I set this to random.exe's directory) which contains a log file named randomProgram.exe_1.log. 
Please, suggest a way to disable the log file generation

Edit: Logs folder is not created by me. I'm assuming it is automatically created by Task Scheduler

Comment: What is log content, how did you create it?

Comment: .. and which logger are you using?